# php - Set variable to result of if statement

Tags: php

I want to set a variable to the result of an if statement in PHP. Is this possible? This is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
 $myVariable = if (strlen($myString) > 0){
               echo '<p>'.$myString.'</p>'
               };
 echo $myVariable;
```

Specifically, I am trying to `echo $myString` into a `<p>` tag but only if `$myString`'s length is more than 0.

I appreciate I am echoing an echo here, but as I'm getting a parse error for the unexpected `if`, I expect my problems lie deeper than that so I'm trying to find out if this can be done at all or if I need to go about it a different way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you trying to set `$myVariable` to `<p>$myString</p>` is the length is > 0?

Comment: `if` is a statement, not a "query". The logic is *if something is true, do something*, not *do if something is true something*.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The way you want to do this...**

To answer the original question re: your formatting, you can use an `if` statement to define a variable, but it's not particularly readable:

```
$myVariable = (strlen($myString) > 0) ? '<p>'.$myString.'</p>' : '';
echo $myVariable;
```

[Live demo](http://eval.in/32410).

**Recommended way to do this...**

However, in your case this is entirely unnecessary, you can use the far more understandable form:

*Note: PHP `echo` does not product an error if passed an undefined variable. It will just echo nothing which I assume is what you want it to do.*

```
if (strlen($myString) > 0) {
    $myVariable = '<p>'.$myString.'</p>';
}
echo $myVariable;
```

[Live demo with `$myString` set and empty for the neighsayers](http://eval.in/32407).

**Added note re `strlen` performance...**

You may find that using `if(isset($myString))` is more efficient than using `if(strlen($myString)>0)`: [isset](http://eval.in/32422) (0.064 sec) vs [strlen](http://eval.in/32421) (0.144 sec). If it is possible for `$myString` to be `undefined` then `strlen` becomes [up to 3x slower still](http://eval.in/32423) (0.5 sec) whilst `isset` [becomes faster](http://eval.in/32424) (0.048 sec).

So your final code should be:

```
if (isset($myString)) {
    $myVariable = '<p>'.$myString.'</p>';
}
echo $myVariable;
```

Comment: it will give an error if $myVariable is not set.

Comment: @Hasina - No it won't, PHP `echo` function doesn't produce an error if fed an `undefined` variable. See my live demos.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer - Glad to help, don't see why this question got closed.

Comment: Me neither. I really wish people would comment when they vote down.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer - For the record I voted up.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be,

```
$myVariable = '';
if (strlen($myString) > 0){
    $myVariable = '<p>'.$myString.'</p>';
};
echo $myVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want to accomplish, just didn't explain it right and thats why you got down voted, anyway:

```
$myVariable = (strlen($myString) > 0 ? '<p>'.$myString.'</p>' : '');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$myVariable=(strlen($myString) > 0)? "<p>$myString</p>" : "";

echo $myVariable;
```

In your code, you miss ; (semicolon) at the end of `echo` that's why you get parse error

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(strlen($myString)>0){
    $myVariable = '<p>'.$myString.'</p>';
}
echo $myVariable;
```